# How to add a new role in Spree?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, spree

I currently have two roles in my system, the defaults, 'User' and 'Admin'.

I would like to add a new role called 'Supplier'.

At the moment the supplier role needs to be the same as a normal user. I have  'frontend' profile edit page. The only difference between the user and supplier is that the supplier has a few more fields they can fill out. I plan on permissioning these extra fields by checking their role against spree_has_role?('supplier')

1. So what's the best way of adding the role to the database (do I add this to an initializer)?
2. How do I then add permissions to this role to be the same as the 'user' role?

At some point I'll want to extend the permissions, but one thing at a time.

I can't  find any clear guide that shows how to do any of this (or at least anything that's been updated in the last year or two). I appreciate if any one can help me out with some instructions / examples.

P.s. I'm using Spree 2.2 Stable with Devise Auth.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regular users have not any particular permission as you can see into the ability model (https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/app/models/spree/ability.rb) . You can just create the role in the database from the console using:

```
Spree::Role.create(name: 'Supplier')
```

If you need to be sure you have this role in the database and you want to put it into an initializer be sure to check if the role is not yet been created. You can use something like:

```
Spree::Role.find_or_create_by_name('Supplier')
```

At this point you can just use in the profile edit view something like:

```
<% if @user.has_spree_role?('Supplier') %>
  ...
  additional fields here
  ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: in Rails 4:
Spree::Role.find_or_create_by(name: 'supplier')